What months should my sun map include?
I'm starting to think about gardening/landscaping and I realize I need to create a sun map.  I know what time of day to record. What I can't seem to find/figure out is what months.  I live in upstate New York, so the seasons come into play.  A couple of websites say to map the equinoxes, which means March & September.  But that just doesn't seem right ("April showers brings May flowers").  A couple of websites mentions map the span of the growing season, which sounds reasonable to me.  Searching for that just brings up frost dates for planting.
So, what span of months should I map?
UPDATE DUE TO COMMENTS:
A sun map maps out which areas receive sunlight at various times throughout the day.  That's how you know which areas receive full sun, part sun, shade, etc.  If you need more information, it's available on the internet (no senses regurgitating it here).
Doing a sun map only once just shows where the sun is at that day of the year.  Due to seasons, the sun moves and areas that receive sun will change from season to season (and possibly month to month).  So, you need to make a sun map to span part of the year.  Which part?  THAT'S the question.  It might be the growing season of plants, but if that's it, please specify because I can't find that information.
I live in an area surrounded by buildings so any changes in the sun angle can make a large difference.
Let me know if there's anything else you don't understand.

I have no idea of what a "Sun map" is, and so (at least for me) it is difficult to answer. What is the purpose? On designing maps/graphs/documents/etc we should keep in mind: what information we want to deliver (which should be useful to viewers)? -- many of us are doing gardening on all months (snow will just change plans, but it causes new works).

Yeah, I do wonder if the term is somewhat subjective.  To me a sun map indicates how much sun the various areas will get during the seasons of interest.   I guess knowing where South is (in the Northern Hemisphere), how tall trees and fences are, and how much shadow the sun casts at different times of the year are the important factors - as once you know that you can work out where best to plant sun loving plants etc.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I suggest making your map for the solstices, which is when the sun will be at its most extreme angles in either direction, and an equinox for a mid point.  Its really helpful for intuiting how the garden will receive the sun all through the year.  There are some nifty phone apps for this.

If your sun map is for planning a productive garden, you can make the map for the beginning and end of your crop's growing season and use every bit of that sun.  'Upstate New York' covers a few gardening zones, I will use 5a (Oneida, NY) as an example.  Here is an example planting schedule for zone 5a, showing you that a cabbage patch wants sunlight in April, but beans won't be looking for it until May.


Thanks.  Although you focused on veggies, I found your "wants sun" part interesting--and that it varies on type of plant.  I did come across a website that said flowering plants only need the max sunlight when they are flowering.  Your answer seems to support that a bit.  If I have time, I'll drive to a nursery and ask about that (will post the answer).  This is important as some parts of my lawn will be in shade during some parts of the year.
